# using alias to where clause query mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have query

```
SELECT p.name,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('', f.name) SEPARATOR ' , ') FROM edu_detail_facility df
        INNER JOIN edu_facility f ON df.id_edu_facility = f.id
        WHERE df.id_edu_provider = p.id) as Fasilitas,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('', a.name) SEPARATOR ' , ') FROM edu_detail_activity da
         INNER JOIN edu_activity a on da.id_edu_activity = a.id
         WHERE da.id_edu_provider = p.id) as Aktifitas
FROM eduprovider p
INNER JOIN edu_lot el ON p.id_school_lot = el.id
INNER JOIN edu_type_of_school et ON p.id_school_tos = et.id
INNER JOIN edu_curriculum ec ON p.id_curriculum = ec.id
INNER JOIN city c ON p.city = c.id
INNER JOIN province pr ON pr.id = p.province
WHERE p.id_school_lot = '6'
AND p.id_school_tos = '4'
AND p.id_curriculum = '5'
AND p.city = '151'
AND p.province = '6'
AND Aktifitas IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
AND Fasilitas IN (1,2,3,4,5)
GROUP BY p.id
```

but mysql showing this error:

`Unknown column 'Aktifitas' in 'where clause'`

why mysql Alias cant be use in Where clause, but is there something I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Your `Aktifitas` is a result of `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('', a.name) SEPARATOR ' , ')` - so `AND Aktifitas IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)` makes no sense. 2)`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use column's alias  in where clause you must repeat the code

(because the where clause is executed  before of the select clause and for this reason the alias name is not know by the where clause )

```
    SELECT p.name,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('', f.name) SEPARATOR ' , ')
         FROM edu_detail_facility df
         INNER JOIN edu_facility f ON df.id_edu_facility = f.id
         WHERE df.id_edu_provider = p.id) as Fasilitas,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('', a.name) SEPARATOR ' , ') 
          FROM edu_detail_activity da
             INNER JOIN edu_activity a on da.id_edu_activity = a.id
             WHERE da.id_edu_provider = p.id) as Aktifitas
    FROM eduprovider p
    INNER JOIN edu_lot el ON p.id_school_lot = el.id
    INNER JOIN edu_type_of_school et ON p.id_school_tos = et.id
    INNER JOIN edu_curriculum ec ON p.id_curriculum = ec.id
    INNER JOIN city c ON p.city = c.id
    INNER JOIN province pr ON pr.id = p.province
    WHERE p.id_school_lot = '6'
    AND p.id_school_tos = '4'
    AND p.id_curriculum = '5'
    AND p.city = '151'
    AND p.province = '6'
    AND (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('', a.name) SEPARATOR ' , ') 
          FROM edu_detail_activity da
             INNER JOIN edu_activity a on da.id_edu_activity = a.id
             WHERE da.id_edu_provider = p.id) IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
    AND (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('', f.name) SEPARATOR ' , ')
         FROM edu_detail_facility df
         INNER JOIN edu_facility f ON df.id_edu_facility = f.id
         WHERE df.id_edu_provider = p.id) IN (1,2,3,4,5)
    GROUP BY p.id
```

eventually you can filter the result using having

```
    SELECT p.name,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('', f.name) SEPARATOR ' , ')
         FROM edu_detail_facility df
         INNER JOIN edu_facility f ON df.id_edu_facility = f.id
         WHERE df.id_edu_provider = p.id) as Fasilitas,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('', a.name) SEPARATOR ' , ') 
          FROM edu_detail_activity da
             INNER JOIN edu_activity a on da.id_edu_activity = a.id
             WHERE da.id_edu_provider = p.id) as Aktifitas
    FROM eduprovider p
    INNER JOIN edu_lot el ON p.id_school_lot = el.id
    INNER JOIN edu_type_of_school et ON p.id_school_tos = et.id
    INNER JOIN edu_curriculum ec ON p.id_curriculum = ec.id
    INNER JOIN city c ON p.city = c.id
    INNER JOIN province pr ON pr.id = p.province
    WHERE p.id_school_lot = '6'
    AND p.id_school_tos = '4'
    AND p.id_curriculum = '5'
    AND p.city = '151'
    AND p.province = '6'
    HAVING Aktifitas IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
    AND   Fasilitas IN (1,2,3,4,5)
    GROUP BY p.id
```